# Соприкосновения коллайдеров unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно, чтобы при соприкосновении пули со стеной она уничтожалась, её уничтожение - не проблема. При создании пули на нее вешается скрипт, на пуле и стене только коллайдер. Я пробовал:
OnCollisionEnter(В скрипте на пуле) не работает - пули пролетают насквозь
OnTriggerEnter(В скрипте на пуле) тоже не работает и пули пролетают насквозь
В обоих случаях я пробовал и с галочкой isTrigger и без нее(только на пуле, если ставить на стенах то персонаж сквозь них проходит)

Comment: На стене / пуле есть Rigidbody? `Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached. `

Comment: ни на стене, ни на пуле Rigidbody нету

Comment: В таком случае добавьте

Comment: добавил Rigidbody на пули, теперь все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Ну ПОЧЕМУ перед тем как публиковать вопрос ВЫ не открыли документацию unity и не попытались там найти информацию? Ведь это прописано первым пунктом в статье про то, как задать хороший вопрос в правилах этого сайта! К тому же таких вопросов про отсутствие rigidobdy - вагон и маленькая тележка!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из документации:

[OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

> Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have
> Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody

Оба объекта должны иметь компонент коллайдера и у одного должен быть включён переключатель `isTrigger` и содержать `Rigidbody`

---

[OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

> Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has
> a non-kinematic rigidbody attached

События столкновения будут отправлены только тогда, когда один из коллайдеров помимо прочего ещё имеет прикреплённый `rigidbody` с галочкой `non-kinematic`